# Is Javascript must to work on Lightning Components?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have no real time experience on working with Lightning Components but while going through the developer guide I see a lot of Javascript code. Is the lightning components can be developed only using the javascript? I had experience on working with visualforce but not on Javascript so is it must to learn javascript before I start development on Lightning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're definitely going to need to get comfortable with both Javascript and probably some jQuery too if you're going to do any amount of Lightning Component Development. I highly recommend you go through the [Trailhead Lightning Components Module](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/lightning_components) to get a taste for what's involved so you'll have a better feel for what you're going to need to know and learn. The Lightning Components Developer's Guide provides you with a [Javascript Cookbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_intro.htm) to help get you started, but not enough to keep you going for long.